# PHP 5.2 upgrade to 5.3

Tags: php, upgrade, phpcodesniffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrade PHP from version 5.2 to 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609325/upgrade-php-from-version-5-2-to-5-3)

I have 15 sites implemented with some functions that are deprecated in PHP 5.3. My hosting provider is offering me a new server, but it has php 5.3 installed on it. I need to upgrade all of my code to 5.3, because the server move is imminent, so I was wondering what's the best way to identify/correct the files that have deprecated functions.

I tried with PHP_Codesniffer, and it's giving me the list of files and the exact functions that won't work in PHP5.3, but I still need to edit the files one by one. Is there another extension/program that could help me with this? (just trying to avoid all of the tedious work of going into all of the files one by one)

Thanks

Comment: P.S. Why not upgrade to 5.4 while you are at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/dev), Notepad2, Notepad++, etc. They all have search & replace in a specified directory. You'll have to do a search & replace for each thing you want to change, but it's faster that doing it one file at a time.

Comment: Hello. I understand, I was going to do that, but I wanted to check if there was a more automatic way of doing it, such as a tool that identifies all of the ocurrences of a certain function in a directory and modifies the php files directly. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Check out this document about the changes between 5.2 and 5.3: http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I already know the list of things I have to change in the migration. I just need to know where they are in my code and how can I do it faster.